# question about Arduino <Control_Surface.h> library

Tags: matrix, arduino, midi, teensy

I'm making a MIDI controller with a 4*4 push button pad by following the example from <Control_Surface.h>, here's the code:

```
#include <Control_Surface.h>

USBMIDI_Interface midi;

using namespace MIDI_Notes;
const AddressMatrix<4, 4> addresses = {{
  {note(C, 4), note(Db, 4), note(D, 4), note(Eb, 4)},
  {note(E, 4), note(F, 4), note(Gb, 4), note(G, 4)},
  {note(Ab, 4), note(A, 4), note(Bb, 4), note(B, 4)},
  {note(C, 5), note(Db, 5), note(D, 5), note(Eb, 5)},
}};

NoteButtonMatrix<4, 4> buttonmatrix = {
  {0, 1, 2, 3}, // row pins
  {4, 5, 6, 7},    // column pins
  addresses,    // address matrix
  CHANNEL_1,    // channel and cable number
};

void setup() {
  Control_Surface.begin();
}

void loop() {
  Control_Surface.loop();
}
```

And I am testing if there is any MIDI signal or not by using a application called "MIDI-OX", my situation is there is no reaction while pushing it; I'm sure there's no connection problem with the circuit when I test the button by whole row and column as one midi note.

May I ask what is the problem with my code? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: did the example work for you?

Comment: It does not work for me, I'm using Teensy 3.2, the button pad I brought from sparkfun (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/button-pad-hookup-guide?_ga=2.95249880.558428050.1615707587-1217305316.1615707587#resources-and-going-further)

Comment: well if the example code doesn't work it is very unlikely your problem is a programming.